# How to mock the second object in the same method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Now I have a method to test using Mockito . However the method is kind of complicated. In the same method ,I need to new two objects both are the same type.

```
Timestamp beginTimestamp = new Timestamp(Long.parseLong(beginTimeLong));
Timestamp endTimestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

I want to mock the second object , `endTimestamp` , to throw an `Exception` , but I can not avoid the influence of  `beginTimestamp`. Now my question is how to mock the second object, `endTimeStamp`, only ,and make it to throw out an exception when I call `endTimestamp's` certain method ,such as:

```
endTimestamp.getTime()
```

I tried  to write my test code which is shown below ,

```
@Ignore
public void getSynPotentialShopBeginTimeAndEndTest4() throws Exception {
    Timestamp beginTimestamp = PowerMockito.mock(Timestamp.class);
    Timestamp endTimestamp = PowerMockito.mock(Timestamp.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(Timestamp.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(beginTimestamp).thenReturn(endTimestamp);

    when(endTimestamp.getTime()).thenThrow(RuntimeException.class);
    redisService.getSynPotentialShopBeginTimeAndEnd();
}
```

It doesn't work either. These code don't have any red wavy underline ,but when I tried to run it, I got an exception like this:

```
 org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
    Incorrect use of API detected here:


You probably stored a reference to `OngoingStubbing` returned by `when()` and called stubbing methods like `thenReturn()` on this reference more than once.
Examples of correct usage:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false).thenThrow(exception);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true, false).thenThrow(exception);
```

Is there another solution I can solve the problem? Anyway , only if the problem to be solved ,that's OK.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 PowerMockito.whenNew(Timestamp.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(beginTimestamp,endTimestamp);
```

Instead of     `PowerMockito.whenNew(Timestamp.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(beginTimestamp).thenReturn(endTimestamp);`